# How to access Marker Border [not size] for PPT Line charts

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am using this code snippet to access the highlighted properties [please see pic], but not sure if I am accessing the right ones. The reason I doubt that, is because when I tried to assign a different set of values to those properties, the code did run, but the changes were not reflected in the chart. To my surprise, those properties were shown in intellisense drop down as hidden members. Does that mean these properties are obsolete now. If yes, then how can I access these properties ? Kindly help.

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To thischart.FullSeriesCollection.Count
      
     Dim EachSeries As Series
     Dim StoreProps(2) as variant

     Set EachSeries = thischart.FullSeriesCollection(i)       
     StoreProps(1) = EachSeries.Border.Color
     StoreProps(2) = EachSeries.Border.Weight

Next
```

**Properties Pic:**

[image]

**Intelli-Sense Pic:**

[image]

**EDIT 1 :** There is a new problem now. When i try to read the `.Border.Weight` property and `Format.Line.Weight` property to an excel, `.Border.Weight` fetches incorrect value. Eg: when set to 5 or 4.75 or 7... manually, it fetches 4. Same issue happens when trying to set both properties as well. `.Border.Weight` doesn't get set correctly.

In the documentation, there is this warning regarding border object. I wonder if this is causing the issue. If so, what could be a workaround to get/set both properties together.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Format.Line` properties

```
 StoreProps(1) = EachSeries.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
 StoreProps(2) = EachSeries.Format.Line.Weight
```

Comment: It works but kinda weird that 'EachSeries.Format.Line.Weight' sets the line width as well as the border width which is under marker option.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you have a solution for a case where I have to set the border weight as 7 and the line weight as 5. Doing it through code doesn't set the border weight correctly. Similarly when fetched to an excel, correct border weight  isn't  being fetched.